# x-tag event delegation: accessing the root element

Tags: javascript, x-tag

I need to delegate a 'tap' event to a close button in a custom element, and in turn call a `close()` method on the root element.  Here is an example:

```js
xtag.register('settings-pane', {
  lifecycle: {
    created: function () {
      var tpl = document.getElementById('settings-pane'),
          clone = document.importNode(tpl.content, true);
      
      this.appendChild(clone);
    }
  },
  events: {
    'tap:delegate(button.close)': function (e) {
      rootElement.close(); // <- I don't know the best way to get rootElement
    }
  },
  methods: {
    close: function () {
      this.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<template id="settings-pane">
  <button class="close">✖</button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

​Hey there, this is the library author, let me clear this up:

For any listener you set in the DOM, X-Tag or vanilla JS, you can always use the standard property `e.currentTarget` to access the node the listener was attached to. For X-Tag, whether you're using the `delegate` pseudo or not, `e.currentTarget` will always refer to your custom element:

```
xtag.register('x-foo', {
  content: '<input /><span></span>',
  events: {
    focus: function(e){
      // e.currentTarget === your x-foo element
    },
    'tap:delegate(span)': function(e){
      // e.currentTarget still === your x-foo element
      // 'this' reference set to matched span element
    }
  }
});
```

Remember, this is a standard API for accessing the element an event listener was attached to, more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: This **is** the correct way to do it.  I forgot about event.currentTarget.  I have some refactoring to do.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to this problem, after dealing with it for several months, is to create another "pseudo", similar to the `:delegate()` pseudo, but that calls the callback differently.  This adds the `:descendant()` pseudo to xtag:

```
xtag.pseudos.descendant = {
    action: function descendantAction(pseudo, event) {
        var match,
            target = event.target,
            origin = target,
            root = event.currentTarget;
        while (!match && target && target != root) {
            if (target.tagName && xtag.matchSelector(target, pseudo.value)) match = target;
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        if (!match && root.tagName && xtag.matchSelector(root, pseudo.value)) match = root;
        return match ? pseudo.listener = pseudo.listener.bind({component: this, target: match, origin: origin}) : null;
    }
};
```

You would use this exactly as you would `:delegate()`, but `this` will reference an object which will in turn reference the target element (the element matching the CSS selector e.g. `button.close`), the origin (the element that received the event), and the component (the custom element itself).  Usage example:

```
xtag.register('settings-pane', {
    methods: {
        close: function () {
            this.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    },
    events: {
        'tap:descendant(button.close)': function (e) {
            this.origin;    // <button> or some descendant thereof that was tapped
            this.target;    // <button> element
            this.component; // <settings-pane> element

            this.component.close(); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For the sake of making sure the correct answer is most prominent, can you please bump the one I've added specifying the intended use of the standard event.currentTarget property in this case.